# iPhone SDK: Why is my view not lining up?

Tags: iphone

When I run my app, for some reason the view is pushed up too far. The space it is pushed up too far appears to be the height of the status bar. (

I am using a NIB. I have verified that both MainWindow and this view has the simulated status bar checked.

I'm not sure what could be wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe double check that the height of the windows are indeed 480?  It fails to reset them and sometimes leave them at 460 when you uncheck the status bar.

Comment: Yes, that is almost it. Once I followed your suggestion, the bottom of the view is aligned in the window. However, I have a navigation bar at the top that is being covered by what seems to be the height of a status bar. Mmmm?????

Comment: Hmm.  I must say I never use the simulate thing in IB.. it seems to cause problems.  If you disable the simulate, and just make the view the height you want (480 - (height of status bar and/or nav bar)) it should align properly.  You could also try keeping the simulate bar in the window, but just removing from the view.

Comment: This will adjust for problems with the simulated status bar.


 //adjusts for IB re-sizing status bar issues
 CGRect  frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    [[self view] setFrame:frame];